# VBA - Get Long Integer into Byte Array?

Tags: arrays, vba, long-integer

I'm trying to get a random number Long Int (4 bytes) into the last 4 bytes of a byte array (Dim MybyteArray (1 to 16) As Byte). Can't see a simple way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: This looks pretty similar to what you're doing. http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2066

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses little endian data. Each byte is normal, big to leftmost and small to rightmost. But the bytes are in reverse order. by LSBit to MSBit

```
00000000, 11111111, 22222222, 33333333

LSByte                         MSByte
```

Or In Hex

```
&h01, &h23, &h45, &h67 = &h67452301
```

Intel uses Little endian and Motorola uses big endian.